# Can't import functions from different module in the same project

Tags: python, python-import

I have two scripts:
script1:

```
from test import script2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

script2:

```
def foo():
    print 'hello'
```

In the structure:

```
test:
│   A
│-----B:
│       script2.py
│script1.py
```

I am trying to call the function `foo()` from script2.py in script1.py.

I received the error:

> This inspection detect names that should resolve but don't. Due to
>   dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but
>   useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level itesm are supported
>   better than instance items.

[image]

I read number of similar cases but they didn't help me:
[Call a function from another file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python)
[How to import a function from parent folder in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622183/how-to-import-a-function-from-parent-folder-in-python)
[Import Script from a Parent Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951255/import-script-from-a-parent-directory)

Comment: You need to make it a package with `__init__.py` files.

Comment: You need to import from `test.A.B`. Also you need `__init__.py` files in each folder

Comment: What they said above, **or**, you add B to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Check your _cwd_ (which by default is appended to _PYTHONPATH_), not to be inside the package. Also, *\_\_init\_\_.py* files in any folder you want to be a package.

Comment: @cricket_007 I put `__init__.py` in each folder and in `script2.py` I added `from A.B.script2 import *` now it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: `from test import script2` doesn't *ever* create a name other than `script2` in the local namespace. It certainly won't, under any circumstances whatsoever, provide something named `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python packages to work, you need `__init__.py` files in the folders. These can be empty.

Then, you are importing from a subfolder, so you need `import script2 from A.B`

At that point, you may use `script2.foo()`

Also worth mentioning that Python3 should be targeted for any new projects .